# Tranparent background won't work form ComboBoxItem under windows 7

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-7-x64

I've been developping some C# code running on Windows XP.

I have a Combobox, its items background is transparent.
When I launch the program under Windows 7, the background of items is white instead of transparent.
If I change transparent to red or any color, it workds(red value gives red color). But transparent gives white...

The code is the following :

```
<Window.Resources>
     <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Transparent"/>
     <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="White"/> (...)
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
     <ComboBox Name="myComboBox" Width="200" Height="100" Margin="40,0,0,256" BorderBrush="Transparent" Foreground="White">
        <ComboBox.Style>
            <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
            </Style>
        </ComboBox.Style>

</Grid>
```

Any advice ?

Thank you all in advance,
Demasiado.

Comment: I see you placed a transparent border - not background

Comment: The tranparency is given by the SolidColorBrush(Window.Resources).

Comment: Only for highlited items - not for the control itself

Comment: Yes, you're right, I correct my post with the full not working code.

Comment: Combobox's background's don't work like that due to the control's complexity and multiple parts - you'll have to apply a new style/template - see my answer

Comment: So why does it work fine with Windows XP ?

Comment: haven't had XP in quite a while to test but seems like an issue with XP's control itself - or a change in control behaviour on later releases - anyway the correct way to do it is to style the control itself

Comment: also to note - WPF has different defaults for control styles in XP, vista/7 and 8 (XP uses classic, vista/7 uses aero and 8 uses aero2) - that could explain it to

Comment: I saw that seaching for answers. I'm quite disspointed cause I already spend much time to set up my apps look&feel, and changing OS causes much rework. By the way it still has to work under Windows XP...
Looking at the MSDN, it seems like It's gonna take quite some time and lines code to configure my small ComboBox !

Comment: have you tryed my exemple below? quite basic really - you'd probably want to remove the shadow effect too maybe - depending on your needs

Comment: Yes, just tried it. It's really good, I will use it.
Though, reading the MSDN I understood I should act on the "popup", so I don't understand how you get a transparent effect on the popup with out writting something like "<Popup x:Name="Popup"> ....</Popup>".
I'm new to C# (used to C++, Java for example) and I'm quite lost with the pages and pages of properties for controls.
I'd prefer to understand what I'm writing, but for now thank you much for this working code !

Comment: Mark as answer if it worked for you - also - there IS a <Popup x:Name="Popup" ...>....</Popup> in that style shown in the MSDN site - but am not sure you can access directly the one used in the system - you could try target a style at Popup

Answer (score 0):

You're putting the highlited item with a transparent background but the control itself still has a background - and it's white

look at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752094(v=vs.110).aspx) for the full style that is applyed to a combobox. i think what you are looking for it to make the dropdown part have a transparent background

if You only want the transparent popup and no other change, this should do it:

```
<ComboBox Name="myComboBox" Width="200" Height="100" Margin="40,0,0,256" BorderBrush="Transparent" Foreground="White">
    <ComboBox.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}" Color="Transparent" />
    </ComboBox.Resources>
</ComboBox>
```

Note that transparent won't make it fully transparent but rather like tainted glass or something - at least in Windows 8 - due to the shadow effect

Comment: Wrong, My post just missed some code, my mistake. The control has a tranparent backgroud, and it is indeed transparent. But the background of the items(all of them, highlighted or not) is white instead of transparent.